# opacity issue - also setting image

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have an issue with the opacity setting my image as well. Is there a way to not set the opacity of my image?

```
<div id="divShow" runat="server" visible="false" 
        style="opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40); background-color:Black; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:10; top:0; left:0; position:fixed;">
   <table>

   <tr><td align="center">
       <asp:Image ID="imgShow" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Car.jpg"/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClose" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" 
                   Width="200px" 
           style="top: 196px; left: 60px; position: absolute; height: 16px">Close</asp:LinkButton>
   </td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: retagged as asp.net and css, rather than jquery which isn't used at all in the example.

Comment: Dont get your issue. isnt opacity working? or you want alternatives to opacity?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `rgba()`. Set your style to the following:

```
#divShow {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

keep `-ms-filter` before `filter` if you want it to work properly in all version of IE.

## //EDIT

Here is **your** code with the **new** styles:

```
<div id="divShow" runat="server" visible="false" 
        style="height:100%; width:100%; z-index:10; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:black; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)"; filter: alpha(opacity=40);">
   <table>
       <tr>
          <td align="center">
             <asp:Image ID="imgShow" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Car.jpg"/>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClose" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" width="200px" style="top: 196px; left: 60px; position: absolute; height: 16px">
                Close
             </asp:LinkButton>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is if you want the background to be transparent to a degree but **not** the content.

Comment: @ max, yes, i just want the background, not my image. But this doesnt work.

Comment: @jack, I've updated the answer with the new css included into the actual html.

Comment: I've pretty much copied what you updated, ran my project and I got an error ... "The server tag is not well formed" on the div tag. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a link to the project I could view?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to not set the opacity
>   of my image?

Ummm...if you don't won't it opaque, don't add the CSS to make it opaque?